# right layout for logitech mx keys

Tags: keyboard

I bought a logitech keyboard (mx keys), the layout is the "qwerty us international" ([see picture here](https://resource.logitech.com/w_900,h_900,c_limit,q_auto,f_auto,dpr_1.0/d_transparent.gif/content/dam/logitech/en/products/keyboards/mx-keys/gallery/us-int-mx-keys-gallery-graphite-front.png?v=1)).

In my daily work I need to use French, so I need to use the following letter for example: éèç.

In my setting I have a lot of layout and I don't know what is best for this keyboard and my use.

I tested the following but I cannot find a "compose" key for the è for example. ctrl or alt gr do nothing (altgr + e or ctrl + e), ctrl + `+ e neither.
[image]

### Edit

Ok i found the good layout : `English US, intl. AltGr Unicode combining`

the advantage of this layout is that it allows you to make the `~ symbols without having to press twice (this is the case with certain layouts)

to make the special symbols you have to do, for example: e then altGr and `which will give è

Just for information for windows you have to use the "United-State International QWERTY" layout and you can use AltGr and e for é for example (simpler ^^ but ~ `must be pressed twice)

Answer (score -1):

To complete, you can change physically the layout of your logitech keyboard.

I had the problem when the layout showed in the gnome GUI settings, was right but when I pressed a touch, the touch highlight in the GUI was wrong.

[documentation](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/promo/mxsetup/keyboard-setup/wireless-receiver.html)

Comment: On a Linux or Unix system?